# How to replace function parameter with correct type?

Tags: typescript

How can I properly declare the type for the sample code below.
data can have a value of either number or string, and can have a variable amount of keys, which should match the keys of format properties.

```
 const data = {'a':1,'b': 2,'c':3} // can be const data = {'a':'title', 'b':'heading', 'c':'paragraph'}
    
    type FormatProperties = Record<string,string>;
    
    const map : FormatProperties = 
    {'a':'center',
    'b':'left',
    'c':'right'};
    
    const myData = [ [data, map], [data,map]]
    
    // myData and data can be any length.
    // how can i replace object[] with proper typing.
    
    const process = (tobeProcessed: object[]) => {
    
            console.log(Object.values(tobeProcessed[0])[1]);
    
    }
    
    process(myData);
```

Comment: would you mean `tobeProcessed: typeof myData` ?

Comment: Do you mean `Record<string,string|number>` ?

Comment: something along the lines of  Array<Array<typeof data, record<string, string>>>

Comment: It depends on what you consider to be the proper for `myData`.

Answer (score 0):

```
type Data= Record<string, string | number>
type FormatProperties = Record<string,string>
type MyData = Array<[TData, FormatProperties]>
```